# Contentful - Add a target=“_blank” to hyperlink within Rich Text

Tags: contentful

Does anyone know how to add a target="_blank" to external hyperlinks within the Rich Text in Contentful?

This is one way I was able to get it to work

```js
[INLINES.HYPERLINK]: (node, children) => {
  if (node.data.uri.includes('https://')) {
    return (
      <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={node.data.uri}>
        {children}
      </a>
    )
  }

  return <Link to={node.data.uri}>{children}</Link>
},
```